# 実行の際に、[Errno 2] No such file or directoryと表示されます

Tags: python, macos

私は以前から、少々複雑な計算をする際にpythonを利用しております（使用pc: Mac-OS, コードの書き込み: Atom, 計算の実行: ターミナル という状況です）。

業務上の事情によりPCを新しく買い替え、その際、以下のような形で以前のPCで行ってきた計算の内容を反映させようとしたのですが、"No such file or directory"と、エラーが表示されます。

```
ユーザー名@MacBook-Air ~ % ls /Users/ユーザー名/Desktop/研究関連/python_lesson
script-2.py script.py

ユーザー名@MacBook-Air ~ % python script-2.py                               
/Users/ユーザー名/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/bin/python: can't open file 'script-2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

上記のように、指定したフォルダの中に結果を反映させてたいファイルが入っていることを確認できていることから、PCを交換したことに伴い、パスがうまくいかなくなった可能性が考えられそうです。

一つ気になっているのは、pythonのバージョンが上記のファイルを開こうとした際に、"3.6.5"と表記されているのですが、script-2.pyのファイル自体を開いたところ、"3.8.2"と書いてあったことから、バージョンが変わったことも関連しそうかと考えられそうです。

以上乱文で恐縮ですが、どなたかご回答いただけますと幸いです。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

プロンプトの表示を見るにカレントディレクトリはホームディレクトリ (`~`) のようですが、実行しようとしているプログラムは別のディレクトリに保存されているため、"ファイルが見つからない" とエラーになっています。

ファイルの保存場所に移動してから実行、もしくはファイルを絶対パスで指定してください。

**保存場所に移動してから実行:**

```
$ cd /Users/ユーザー名/Desktop/研究関連/python_lesson
$ python script-2.py
```

**絶対パスで指定して実行:**

```
$ python /Users/ユーザー名/Desktop/研究関連/python_lesson/script-2.py
```